# Can Apache Tika (or any JVM library) produce ordered extract data referencing images, as well as text, e.g. from a PDF?

Tags: extract, apache-tika, text-extraction

Basically, I want to be able to create a set of 'slides' based on extracts from documents such as PDFs or Word docs, programmatically.

For this, **I need to know [roughly] where in the text any embed images were originally placed**, as such, simply dumping the image resources out to disk *wouldn't* help*.

I'm a Java dev, so I don't fear the code ;-)

*unless of course there are references within the [Tika] extract output, at the appropriate position(s) or line(s).

Comment: This might help me => https://tika.apache.org/1.8/api/org/apache/tika/parser/pdf/PDFParserConfig.html#setExtractInlineImages(boolean)

Comment: Can't you just look for the `<img>` tag in the Tika HTML output to know where they go?

Comment: @Gagravarr - Can you [look for the <img> tag]? To date, I've only used Tika's jar gui, none of the PDF derived outputs appeared to include image data, do you know how I'd specify this, in code?

Comment: If you're using the Tika App single jar, then just run it with `--html` and look at the output. For most formats you'll get an `img` tag where the embedded image lived